# temporaly remove cluster when show popup with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

I'm trying to open leaflet popup with external (out of the map) links. My code works well but when targets are in a cluster, it doesn't expand and the popup is not showed.

Here is my JS:

```js
var center = {lat:48.835797462431, lon:2.35107421875};
var abp_umap = null;
var markCluster;
var markers = [];
var umusers = {
 "557":{"lat":48.8168,"lon":2.488,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test01\">test01<\/a>"},
 "2191":{"lat":48.8168,"lon":2.488,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test02\">test02<\/a>"},
 "979":{"lat":49.8168,"lon":2.488,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test03\">test03<\/a>"},
 "235":{"lat":52.597,"lon":13.1211,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test04\">test04<\/a>"},
 "2193":{"lat":45.9238,"lon":6.86933,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test05\">test05<\/a>"},
 "2192":{"lat":44.6333,"lon":-1.0667,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test06\">test06<\/a>"},
 "2190":{"lat":43.8347,"lon":4.3614,"img":"<a href=\"#\" class=\"popmap\" title=\"test07\">test07<\/a>"}}
function init_map() {
  abp_umap = L.map("abp_usermap").setView([center.lat, center.lon], 5);
  markCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
  L.tileLayer("//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org" title="OpenStreetMap">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(abp_umap);
  L.control.scale().addTo(abp_umap);
  for (user in umusers) {
   var uIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl:"https://forum.raspfr.org/images/Raspberry_Pi_logo.png", iconSize:[25, 32], iconAnchor: [12.5,16], popupAnchor :[(25/2)-12.5,-16]});
   var marker = L.marker([umusers[user].lat, umusers[user].lon], { icon: uIcon }).bindPopup(umusers[user].img, {className:''});
      markers[user] = marker;
   markCluster.addLayer(marker);
  }
  abp_umap.addLayer(markCluster);
}
$(function() {
 init_map();
 $("#centerme").click(function() { abp_umap.setView([48.835797462431, 2.35107421875]); return false; });
 $("#rzoom").click(function() { abp_umap.setZoom(5); return false; });
 $(".popmap").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      mypop = markers[this.id];
      abp_umap.setView([umusers[this.id].lat, umusers[this.id].lon]);
      abp_umap.setZoom(14);
      mypop.openPopup();
      return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.4.1/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="popmap" id="557" title="test01">test01</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="2191" title="test02">test02</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="979" title="test03">test03</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="235" title="test04">test04</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="2193" title="test05">test05</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="2192" title="test06">test06</a>, <a href="#" class="popmap" id="2190" title="test07">test07</a>
<br /><div id="abp_usermap" style="height:200px;"></div><br />
```

Anyone has any idea to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

`markerCluster` objects have their own click events - `clusterclick`. You need to listen for those if you want something to happen when a cluster is clicked.

See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#events

Comment: Hello, I don't want to click on clusters, I want that if a link which is in a cluster (test1, test2 or test3 in my example) is clicked, the cluster is expanded and the popup for the concerned pin is showed. Actually, I'm looking at the way to spiderify the cluster, so the pins are showed. And this without any user action on the map, only with JS when clicking the link OUT of the map

Answer (score 0):

I think I could use `{disableClusteringAtZoom: 14}` (14 is the zoom level I use to focus a pin), it's not the more efficient but it seems to work.
Any other idea is welcome :)